# ¿Cómo desactivar un día de la semana input Date?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Estoy intentando limitar un input date para que no se pueda seleccionar una fecha más de 3 días, empezando por el día siguiente al actual y además que los domingos tampoco sean seleccionables. Mi problema es que colisionan ambas restricciones y me cuenta los domingos como un día más dentro de los seleccionables pero al haber desactivado el domingo no es clicable pero tampoco añade un día más que si sea seleccionable.

## Funcion JQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var tomorrow = new Date();
        var finfecha = new Date();
        tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
        finfecha.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
        $('#id_fecha_entrega').datepicker({minDate: tomorrow, maxDate: finfecha, beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [(day != 0), ''];
        }});
        $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
            closeText: 'Cerrar',
            prevText: '<Ant',
            nextText: 'Sig>',
            currentText: 'Hoy',
            monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
            dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
            weekHeader: 'Sm',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            firstDay: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: ''
        };
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
    });
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es confusa, ¿esto qué quiere decir exactamente?: *para que no se pueda seleccionar una fecha más de 3 días, empezando por el día siguiente*  ¿El día siguiente a qué?

Comment: El día siguiente al actual. Modificaré la pregunta.

Comment: excluir solo domingos? o alguna lista de fechas en especial?

Comment: En SOes no la encuentro y me suena mucho.. mira [esta de SOeng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34133670/3045491)

Comment: es medio un clásico aqui hay otro ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/a/41499438/1423096

Comment: la onda es contar los dias y probar si alguno es domingo y si es domingo sumas un dia mas al end date. el que no encuentro es el de pasarle una lista de dias feriados pero se puede armar tambien probando si esta en la lista sumas un dia mas

Comment: la función que hay dentro de beforeshowday hace algo así, comprueba si el dia == 0 devuelve una cadena vacía, pero no sé como hacer que cuente uno más

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder conseguir lo que queria he tenido que comprobar que dia de la semana estaba para añadirle un día más a la lista de días que podía seleccionar, ya que no hay forma de "saltarse" un día de la semana.

Pongo como ha quedado mi código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var tomorrow = new Date();
        var finfecha = new Date();
        tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
        if (tomorrow.getUTCDay() >= 5){
            finfecha.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 3);
        }else{
            finfecha.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
        }
        $('#id_fecha_entrega').datepicker({minDate: tomorrow, maxDate: finfecha, beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [(day != 0), ''];
        }});
        $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
            closeText: 'Cerrar',
            prevText: '<Ant',
            nextText: 'Sig>',
            currentText: 'Hoy',
            monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
            dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
            weekHeader: 'Sm',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            firstDay: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: ''
        };
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
    });
```